# Зависание приложения в winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Стоит задача по нажатию на кнопочку в приложении выбирать параметры в двух комбобоксах на сайте и там же нажимать кнопочку.
Вот код:

```
HtmlWindow frames = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0];
var elements = frames.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
elements[0].SetAttribute("value", "1");
elements[1].SetAttribute("value", "1");
var elements1 = frames.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
elements1[0].InvokeMember("click");
```

Всё работает гладко, нажимаю кнопку в приложении, всё что нужно происходит на сайте, очень быстро нажимаю кнопочку (от руки) быстро всё и на сайте происходит. Но как только я вставляю код в цикл, приложение после нажатия на кнопочку сразу зависает.

Условие выхода из цикла есть, 100%. Для теста пробовал даже через `for` ставить 2-3 прохода по циклу, не больше, всё равно зависает. Подозреваю, что сайт не успевает отвечать на код, который в цикле. Как это можно предотвратить? Если использовать `webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted`, то как будет выглядеть обработчик? Ведь я работаю в цикле. Если это надо было бы сделать единоразово, то без проблем, но с циклом возникают проблемы.

Comment: Покажите ваш цикл

Comment: Ну, допустим выше описанный код будет в цикле for(int i=0; i<5; i++). Уже в этом цикле приложение зависает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть нужно дать браузеру обрабатывать свои события. Для этого нужно использовать Application.DoEvents(). Как идея:

```
    for (...)
    {

        // событие, которое должно срабатывать после вашей обработки документа
        // я использовал DocumentCompleted, но у вас может быть другое
        bool loaded = false;
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (x, y) => {
            loaded = true;
        };

        // ваши операции .. с документом

        // здесь ждем окончания операции примерно 10 секунд
        int waitCount = 0;
        Application.DoEvents(); // !!!
        while (loaded == false) {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Application.DoEvents(); // !!!
            waitCount++;
            if (waitCount * 50 >= 10000 /*ca. 10 sec*/ )
                throw new Exception("timeout");
        }

    }
```

Comment: А можно это сделать как-нибудь без thread.sleep? Ведь у всех скорость интернета и загруженность ПК в момент выполнения операции разные... Кому-то нужно 200 миллисекунд, кому-то больше

Comment: Протестировал, код работает как часики, но хотелось бы всё таки избежать использование Thread.Sleep(); Если это возможно, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

1. Загрузка страницы происходит в UI'ном потоке.
2. Ты обращается к документу после того, как инициирован переход.

Comment: Как  мне поправить ситуацию ?